# Return 2 properties from a list using lambda ID(distinct) and the count of the specific ID?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

ASP.NET MVC(C# using VS2015), trying to build a simple webshop in a scool -project.

So I have a table with a list of food-disches with the properties
`ID`, `Name`, `Description`, `Price` and `Type`

```
List<food> model = (List<food>)Session["shoppingbasket"];
```

I would like to get the number of the distinct disches(ID) and the count of these before placing the order.

Is this possible?

tried something like :

```
int total = model.Select(i => i.foodID).Distinct().Count();
```

but of course this only returns the number of the distinct dishes in my list.

I need to list the ID and the count of that specific ID. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `GroupBy` on `FoodID` and then project the result to get `FoodID` and it's count like:

```
var result = model.GroupBy(i => i.foodID)
                  .Select(x=>new { DishID = x.Key,Count = x.Count()})
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ty, it seems to work! Is it okay to add a orderID(constant value i have retrived from earlier) like this?    var result = model.GroupBy(i => i.MatrattID)
                   .Select(x => new { DishID = x.Key, BestID = bestallningsid, Count = x.Count() })
                   .ToList();